# Grid Template Areas not responding

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I don't know where I'm going wrong but the grid-template-areas is refusing to put my grid-area:image3 into the second row, far right. Instead it is on an unwanted 3rd row. Can anyone help? Sorry if I've formatted things incorrectly. This is my ever question.

```css
#main{
  background-color: #DEDF5F;
  font-family: calibri;
}
#title{
font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 60px; 
}
h1{
  font-family: calibri;
  text-align: center;
}
#image{
  grid-area: image;
  width: 20%;
}
#image2{
  grid-area: image2;
  width: 20%;
}
#image3{
  grid-area: image3;
  width: 20%;
}
#tribute-info{
  grid-area: info;
  width:20%;
}
.grid-container{
 display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'image info image2' 'image info image3';
}
```

Vincent Van Gogh

## The greatest artist of all time?

Self-portrait by Van Gogh, painted in 
                    1889.

### A Brief Timeline of his Life

1869-begins work at Goupil & Cie, an art dealers' in The 
                     Hague.

1873- transfered to the London branch.

1875-transfered to Paris and sacked a year later.

1876- becomes a teacher in England.

1877- tries studying for his university theology 
                     entrance exams.

1879-becomes a pastor in a very poor mining area of 
                     Belgium.

1880-enrols at the Académie Royale des Beaux-Arts art 
                     school in Brussels.

1881- unsuccessfully tries to marry his cousin.

1883- moves to northern Belgium to his parents' house.

1885- his work was exhibited for the first time.

1886- enters the Academy of Fine Arts in Antwerp then 
                    moves to Paris after a few months.

1888- moves to the Yellow House in Arles, southern 
                     France. Gauguin visits and Vincent loses his ear.

1889- spends a year in an asylum

1890- tries unsuccessfully to commits suicide but soon 
                     dies from his wound.

```
               <div class="grid-item">
                  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dytmcam8b/image/upload/v1530297645/490px-Van_Gogh_Portrait_of_the_Postman_Joseph_Roulin_cicrl7.jpg" alt="Portait of Postman" id="image3">
               </div>

               <div class="grid-item">
                 <p style="font-size: 30px"> If you would like to learn 
                 more, click <a href=" 
                 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh" 
                 id="tribute-link" target="_blank" >here</a>.</p>
               </div>
            </body>
```

Comment: can you please include your html

Comment: Add `display: grid` to your `.grid-container`. All grid properties are being ignored.

Comment: I don't see no `display:grid`

Comment: I've added the display: grid but the image3 is still on a line below image, instead of being below image2.

Comment: I seem to have solved it...it might have been about my html. I didn't have my ids all in beside the actual grid item. They were beside the grid item tag. I think.